# Why is es6 import coming as empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify

I'm making a chrome plugin. For now, I have the class "GetLink" which should simply grab the first link that appears in the active tab's DOM. Here is the code:

```
    export class GetLink {
        constructor() {
            chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, tabs => {
                this.ajaxGet(
                    `${tabs[0].url}`,
                    data => this.getLink(data),
                    error => {throw new Error(`AJAX GET failed because response was ${error}`)}
                );
            });
        }

        ajaxGet(url, success, error) {
            if(!window.XMLHttpRequest) throw new Error(`This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest`);
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if(request.readyState === 4) {
                    if(request.status !== 200) {
                        console.log(request.status)
                        if(error && typeof error === "function") {
                            error(error);
                        }
                    }
                    if(success && typeof success === "function") {
                        success(request.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };
            request.open("GET", url);
            request.send();
        }

        getLink(data) {
            let nodeList = document.createElement("html");
            nodeList.innerHTML = data;
            return nodeList.querySelector("a").href;
        }
    }
}
```

This functionality works fine if I remove the export and call it directly with:

```
new GetLink()
```

But when I try to import it into app.js (the entry point) I get an empty object. app.js is in the same directory as getLink.js and is imported, assigned, and the results logged to the console:

```
import {GetLink} from "./getLink";
let link = new GetLink();
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(link)}`); // outputs {} in the popup console
```

I am using an npm script to build this to minified, transpiled, browser-safe es5. Here is the package.json with the relevant scripts:

```
{
  "name": "getALink",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "latest",
    "uglify-js": "latest",
    "babel-cli": "latest",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "latest",
    "babelify": "latest",
    "browserify": "latest",
    "watch": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "installClean": "rm -rf node_modules && npm install",
    "lint": "jshint src/scripts/app.js || true",
    "build": "mkdir -p app/js/ && browserify src/js/app.js -t [babelify --presets [es2015]] | uglifyjs -m -o app/js/app.min.js",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run build' src/"
  },
  "author": "HelloWorld",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the import statement? getLink.js must be exported or I would get a type error. Maybe something is wrong with the way I am using babel or browserify?

Comment: Your class totally works. It just doesn't have any properties that would show up in a `JSON.stringify`. Try `console.log(link)` instead.

Comment: Are you saying "the functionality" does not work when instantiated after the import? Or that the log does what you expect when you run it in the same module, without exporting?

Comment: You really should not be using a class at all for this. It doesn't have any state, no instance properties, no nothing. A constructor should not have side effects. You're better off exporting a plain function (or multiple functions).

Comment: the log does work when you do it in the same module, without exporting

Comment: And what does it log there?

Comment: OK I can do it without a class. I still want to know why it isn't working. When I remove JSON.stringify() I get [object Object]... 
 
If I do a "new GetLink" in the same file as the class I get the first link from the active tab's DOM" which is what I want

Comment: Please remove not only the `JSON.stringify`, but also the template literal stringification so that you log the actual object and can inspect it

Comment: OK now I get the entire class